# How to get an object item by key without a foreach in PHP

Tags: php, object, cakephp

I'm struggling with something that looks quite straightforward. I have an object with several items in it and I'm not able to get one single item without a foreach.

Here's the object where I'm talking about:

```
object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet) id:0 {
'items' => [
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Album) id:1 {
'id' => (int) 1
'name' => 'Album 1'
'images' => [ ]
'[new]' => false
'[accessible]' => [ ]
'[dirty]' => [ ]
'[original]' => [ ]
'[virtual]' => [ ]
'[hasErrors]' => false
'[errors]' => [ ]
'[invalid]' => [ ]
'[repository]' => 'Albums'
},
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Album) id:5 {
'id' => (int) 3
'name' => 'Album 3'
'images' => [ ]
'[new]' => false
'[accessible]' => [ ]
'[dirty]' => [ ]
'[original]' => [ ]
'[virtual]' => [ ]
'[hasErrors]' => false
'[errors]' => [ ]
'[invalid]' => [ ]
'[repository]' => 'Albums'
},
(int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\Album) id:9 {
'id' => (int) 5
'name' => 'Album 5'
'images' => [ ]
'[new]' => false
'[accessible]' => [ ]
'[dirty]' => [ ]
'[original]' => [ ]
'[virtual]' => [ ]
'[hasErrors]' => false
'[errors]' => [ ]
'[invalid]' => [ ]
'[repository]' => 'Albums'
},
]
}
```

This is what I initially thought that would work:

```
$albums['0']
```

But it returns this error:

```
Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\ResultSet as array
```

After searching around (search string 'php object get first item without foreach', I tried a couple of other things, but without success:

```
$albums->{'1'}
key($albums)
```

Could someone show me the light here? :)

Thank you!

Sam

Comment: Apply `toArray` to resultSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the first item, you can use `first()` :

```php
$firstAlbum = $albums->first();

// access the properties
$firstAlbumId = $firstAlbum->id;
$firstAlbumName = $firstAlbum->name;
```

`$albums` is an object of `Cake\ORM\ResultSet` and cannot be treated as an array. To convert `ResultSet` object to an array, you can use `toArray()` :

```php
$albumsArray = $albums->toArray();
$firstAlbum = $albumsArray[0];
```